# how to load some cols of Object with many-to-many relationship in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, load, many-to-many

There is a problem with loading the object from the database using Hibernate.

I have three  java classes: "A", "B" and "C".
**A and B** are associated as mamy-to-many relationship by an additional table "a_join_b".
**A and C** are associated as many-to-one relationship.

There is code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class AclassEnt implements java.io.Serializable{
 @Id
    @TableGenerator(name = "inventory",
        table = "hibernate_sequences",
        pkColumnName = "sequence_name", 
        pkColumnValue = "Emp_Gen", 
        valueColumnName = "sequence_next_hi_value", 
        initialValue = 0,
        allocationSize = 100)  
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE) 
    @Column(name = "A_ID", nullable = false)
    private Integer aId;

    @Column(name = "A_NUMBER", length = 20)
    private String aNumber;

    @Column(name = "A_NAME", length = 15)
    private String aName;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE},
                fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
                targetEntity=WorkersEnt.class)
   @JoinColumn(name="C_ID")
    private CclassEnt cclass;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH,fetch = FetchType.LAZY,targetEntity = BclassEnt.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "A_join_B", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID") })
    private Set<BclassEnt> BclassList=new HashSet<BclassEnt>();

    //getters and settrs
}



 @Entity
 @Table(name = "B")
 public class MeasureTypeEnt implements java.io.Serializable{

 @Id
    @TableGenerator(name = "inventory",
    table = "hibernate_sequences",
    pkColumnName = "sequence_name", 
    pkColumnValue = "Emp_Gen", 
    valueColumnName = "sequence_next_hi_value", 
    initialValue = 0,
    allocationSize = 100)  
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE) 
     @Column(name = "B_ID", nullable = false)
     private Integer bId;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "B_NAME", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String bName;

    //getters and setters   
}
```

Question: how can I load object "AclassEnt" with hext fields: aId, aName,cclass and BclassList ???

Using next code I can load all cols what I need exept one last. I mean "BclassList".

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(AclassEnt.class,"c");
crit.createAlias("cclass", "cclass")
    .createAlias("BclassList", "BclassList")//<-- is it correctly?
    .setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
    .add(Projections.property("c.aId").as("aId"))
    .add(Projections.property("c.aName").as("aName"))
    .add(Projections.property("c.cclass").as("cclass"))
    .add(Projections.property("c.BclassList").as("BclassList"))//<-- is it correctly?
    );

AclassEnt result = crit.setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer( AclassEnt.class )).list();
```

Comment: It's not possible. A criteria query returns either scalars or entities, but not a mix of both. But it seems to me that your query loads everything in A (including its Bs and its C) except the aNumber. Why do you absolutely want ths column not to be loaded?

Comment: JB Nizet, it is just example. In real programm in Aclass more then 20 columns. Now I need to create simple report, where I use only few of them. I think is wrong to load full object (23 columns) when I need only five or six of them.

Comment: Then you'll also have to create projections on B and C properties, and recreate an object graph yourself. I wouldn't care much about the 23 columns. The cost of getting them is probably negligible compared to the cost of executing the query with the joins.

Answer (score 0):

you should have access to your B entity list just with the getter of the A class. In you case Set myAobject.getbClassList();

So you just have to create a query/criteria to retrieve your A entity. Afterwards, just call the getter of your Set and operate with the Set. No need to make complicated queries.
For example: currentSession().get(AclassEnt.class, 1); or currentSession().createCriteria(AclassEnt.class).list(); ...

But take care, if you have a Lazy fetching and you try to access it outside a transaction, you'll get lazyexceptions. A solution is to make lazy fetch eager. And you don't need to instantiate the Set.

I was unsure so I checked the doc, but your unidirection ManyToMany relation definition seems correct: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/ 2.2.5.3.2. Many-to-many